Problem with unsported media type 415 laravel
I want to upload file to external API: https://petstore.swagger.io/#/pet/uploadFile,
but when I added img to my form, I get:

"Unsupported Media Type".

This is my form:
 <form method="POST" action="{{ route('pets.storeImage', $pet['id']) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="petId" class="form-label">PetId</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" required
                               id="petId" name="petId" readonly
                               value="{{ $pet['id'] }}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="metadata" class="form-label">MetaData</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control"
                               id="metaData" name="metaData">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="photoUrls" class="form-label">Photo</label>
                        <input type="file" class="form-control"
                               id="photoUrls" name="photoUrls">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Upload</button>
                </form>

This is my controller :
  public function storeImage(PetServices $petServices, Request $request, $id)
    {
        $response = Http::post('https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/pet/' . $id . '/uploadImage', [
            'photoUrls' => [
                $request->file('photoUrls')->store('pets', 'public')
            ],
            'additionalMetadata' => $request->input('metaData'),
        ]);
        if ($response->successful()) {
            return redirect()->route('pets.show', $id)->with('success', 'image uploaded');
        } else {
            return redirect()->route('pets.show', $id)->with('error', 'failed to upload image');
        }
    }

And also how can I display this img after upload?
I tried to added headers like this: to my controller response
'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'application/json'],

but nothing helped.

what is that you are trying to upload? The format problem might be due to the request's indicated Content-Type or Content-Encoding
